# why having 2 fold() cmds in gremlin request is so heavy in a large graphdb?

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I want to have a command that will add a vertex if it doesn't exists in the graph and I'm using this command to do it

```
g.V().hasLabel('record').has('myId', 2284588).fold().coalesce(unfold(), addV('record').property('myId', 2284588))
```

this will add 1 vertex and I want to be able to do several additions in one request, as I understood it's faster than doing several requests

so the command that will be generated will be something like this

`g.V().hasLabel('record').has('myId', 2284588).fold().coalesce(unfold(), addV('record').property('myId', 2284588)).V().has('myId', 2284581).fold().coalesce(unfold(), addV('record').property('myId', 2284581))`

this works well in a small graph (about 10000 vertices) it takes about 0.1 seconds
but when the graph has about 1M vertices the single addition takes 0.1 seconds and when I do the multiple command it takes 20 seconds

from what I tried it looks like the fold() command is the one that takes so much time but somehow only when it appears more than once

so my main question is why, and whether I'm doing something wrong here...

I'm using gremlin with nodeJS and have a neptune (aws) graphdb

Comment: I had a similar situation, but for my use case, deleting and re-adding the worked really well.

Comment: One way to dig into these types of situation is to use the /profile endpoint and see where the time is being spent. Are you able to send your query (using curl or using the Neptune Notebook) to the /gremlin/profile endpoint and examine the results? That may give some clues that will help. You may also want to post to the Amazon Neptune support forum so that someone can work with you more directly or open a ticket if you are able to.Here is the forum link https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=253

Answer (score 2):

Is 'myId' a unique identifier for each vertex? If it is, you can use that as the actual vertex ID, rather than making it a property. You would then be able to do:

```
g.V('2284588')
 .fold()
 .coalesce(
    unfold(), 
    addV('record').property(t.id, '2284588')
 )
 .V('2284581')
 .fold()
 .coalesce(
    unfold(), 
    addV('record').property(t.id, '2284581')
  )
```

This should improve performance and remain reasonably constant irrespective of dataset size. Note that by using your own custom IDs, you're able to do direct lookups by ID, without having to filter by label or property.

Comment: I see, but I don't think that's the problem.
when I do a request with a single upsert (only 1 fold) it takes 0.1 seconds and when I add the second upsert (2 upserts in 1 request - 2 folds) it takes 20 seconds. So for what it looks like it's not the search process that is the problem, cause also when I remove the second fold it works fast.

Comment: Using a mid-query `V().has()` falls out of Neptune's optimization path. Using `V(<id>`), however, will take advantage of optimized steps throughout the query.